# Is else necessary with a Django pre_save signal?

Tags: django, signals

Model named Scorecard. Scorecard has a `name` CharField with unique. I save .csv files to media folder. I am trying to create a `pre_save` signal that gets the old name (because it may have changed) and checks for .csv file in media to delete it.

When my signal code below is commented out and I create a new instance, a .csv is created in my media folder as-desired.

When I uncomment my signal below, a .csv file is only outputted when I edit and save an existing instance but not when I create one.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Scorecard)
def file_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('INSTANCE ID:', instance.pk)
    if instance.pk is not None:
        old = Scorecard.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        print(old.name)
        file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, ''.join([old.name, '.csv']))
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)
```

I suspect this has to do with the fact that this is an if statement without an else? I've tried `else: return` and `else: pass`. What am I not understanding? If instance is `None`, am I supposed to do something?

Note: I realize going off of the name as the file name is probably poor practice. I'll probably fix that part later by slugifying it or something.

Comment: ... it's only doing it when you edit an existing one because *that's what you explicitly told it to do*, surely?

Comment: Do I have to explicitly state what to do when instance.pk is None when dealing with signals, or is it just supposed to continue onto .save()?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want here. If you want the same thing to happen when it is none as when it is not none, don't have the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Scorecard)
def file_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        old = Scorecard.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if old.name != instance.name:
            # name has been changed
            file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, ''.join([old.name, '.csv']))
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)
    except:
        pass
```

Not this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Scorecard)
def file_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('INSTANCE ID:', instance.pk)
    if instance.pk is not None:
        old = Scorecard.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        print(old.name)
        file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, ''.join([old.name, '.csv']))
        print(file_path)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print('Deleting: {}'.format(file_path))
            os.remove(file_path)
    else:
        print('Instance equals None, do nothing!')
```

The problem I was trying to solve was: I have a celery task that ultimately downloads data from an API, then Pandas takes that data and uses `to_csv(...)` to save the data to my `/media/` folder. What I was trying to do was, if someone edits an existing object and changes the name of it, delete the old file in /media/ because the name is "name".csv.

I think the combination of `pre_save`, a celery delay, and that I have defined `save_model` in my `admin.ModelAdmin` is the cause but I don't fully understand the chain of events yet.

```
class ScorecardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
        result = get_report.delay(name, start, end, type)
        set_task_status.delay(result.task_id)
        obj.task_id = result.task_id
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```